# Weird executabe behaviour

Tags: shell, permissions, executable

I have a server machine with ubuntu 9.10. I am trying to put in place an executable, which turns out to be the latest flashplayer (debugger version).

Somehow the file appears as present and executable, but when launching it the console indicates that the files does not exist:

```
$ pwd
/home/rodrigo/t_fplayer
$ ls -lh
total 12M
-rwxr-xr-x 1 rodrigo rodrigo 12M 2011-07-09 11:35 flashplayerdebugger
$ ./flashplayerdebugger
-bash: ./flashplayerdebugger: No such file or directory
$ ldd flashplayerdebugger
       not a dynamic executable
```

Using the same executable (copied via ssh) in my local machine works fine.

Any idea of what is going on? What can explain this behaviour? Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please [do not crosspost](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq). I'm voting to close here because [this answer on SF](http://serverfault.com/questions/288666/weird-executabe-behaviour/288674#288674) is very likely to be correct and helpful.

Comment: @Gilles: Can we migrate and merge instead?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be a 64 bits <-> 32 bits compatibility issue.

```
~/t_fplayer$ file flashplayerdebugger 
flashplayerdebugger: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```

The solution would be to install ia32-libs.

See answers at https://serverfault.com/questions/288666

Comment: On ubuntu you can install them by running `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` in a terminal

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that /home/rodrigo/t_fplayer/flashplayerdebugger does not have the correct format.  Indeed, the ldd output indicates just as much.

Do: `file /home/rodrigo/t_fplayer/flashplayerdebugger` to see what the file command knows about its format.

It may be one of those fancy "shell scripts" that unpacks an ASCII-encoded file, and then installs it.  Proprietary software vendors are fond of that sort of silliness.